# Debugging Arduino with the Eclipse IDE

Tags: arduino

I have eclipse configured properly in order to upload a file onto my arduino. But now I would like to know if it is possible to debug an arduino only with the eclipse ide? if so are there any instructions which outline how to achieve the same?

Comment: Take a look at this recent, Mar-2022, article on Code Project, Debugging an Arduino project with GDB on Classic ATtiny and Small ATmega MCUs, https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5321801/Debugging-an-Arduino-project-with-GDB-on-Classic-A which describes the debugWIRE protocol.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Arduino board doesn't support debug. In order to debug your code running inside an embedded micro-controller, the board/micro-controller should support debug, by providing functions/resources that a remote debugger, running on your desktop, could call to control the board.

So, in principle, no IDE (Eclipse or any other) could support debug.

But there are some project out there that provides some work-arounds to enable debugging on Arduino via modified libraries. This is not the exact experience you'd have with a real-debugger, but may work in your case. Google for VisualMicro, an Visual Studio plugin to code and debug Arduino software. But, in this case, you would have to use Visual Studio and  Microsoft Windows, instead of Eclipse (Multiplatform)

Comment: This post is old, but I think it needs updating, as it is quite misleading. The standard Arduino board supports "debugWire" debugging, which uses a serial protocol on the reset pin. The 2560 board supports JTAG debugging. You need a debugging board like the AVR Dragon, plus the Atmel Studio IDE. Then you can set hardware breakpoints, single step etc. There is code for making Eclipse do this too, but I have had no luck getting it to work. This post gives more details http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=168996.0

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried to debug arduino, but it does not seem possible, besides using `printf()` or some conditional variables.

Answer (score -3):

I have found this [usefull tutorial](http://awtfy.com/2012/03/29/hardware-debugging-the-arduino-using-eclipse-and-the-avr-dragon/), unfortunately for a best debug experience is necessary an AVR programmer like this: [AVR Dragon](http://www.atmel.com/tools/avrdragon.aspx)

Also look at this for arduino programming

[Arduino playground.](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Eclipse)

and

[Another similar link.](http://www.chipkin.com/using-eclipse-with-arduino-duemilanove)

For me it worked.

Comment: The question isn't about how to program! It's about HOW TO DEBUG